# How to close Entity Framework create foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework.6.1.3. I want Entity Framework to not create foreign key in SQL Server database. What configuration can be set?

I tried this but it only disables foreign key, it still creates it:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Is there a way to tell Entity Framework not to create the foreign keys it in database?

Comment: can you put your model?

Comment: You can just avoid to map the foreign key property (i.e. NotMapped). Otherwise you need to customize the Migration process deleting the foreign key constraint creation.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to have a look at [EntityForeinkey](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s02.html) for you issue I hope you may find it helpful for you

Comment: This isn't an answer, it is a comment. If you specify a link you need to also need to extrapolate the important parts from the link and explain it.